# How to make a Powershell Script that Imports csv, searches for specific phrase and then exports results?

Tags: powershell, csv

I am very new to powershell scripting. I want to make a powershell script that, imports a csv file, searches a column (in this case its called "Tags"), the search phrase is "R3", then gather the results and put it into another csv file.

So pretty much a script that searches specifically for "R3" and then lists all the results in another csv file.

I am new and not even sure if I'm on the right track but this is what I have:

$csv = Import-Csv C:\example.csv
$csv | where {$_.tags -eq "R3"}

Comment: Just add `| Export-CSV results.csv -NoTypeInformation` to the end of `$csv | where {$_.tags -eq "R3"}`